# autoHighLight with AutoComplete and ListItem

Tags: typescript, material-ui

I'm using an AutoComplete component to render a list of ListItem, but when I use the ListItem, it seems like the `autoHighLight` function doesn't work anymore and I couldn't figure out why. Other functions like `filter, clearOnEscape,...` still work just fine.

```
<Autocomplete
              id="selector"
              data-testid="selector"
              filterOptions={filterOptions}
              options={data}
              value={selectedOption}
              autoHighlight
              clearOnEscape
              ListboxComponent={ListboxWithListItem}
</AutoComplete>
```

```
const ListboxWithInfo = (ListboxProps: any) => {
  return (
    <div role={"listbox"}>
      <List {...ListboxProps}>
        {ListboxProps &&
          ListboxProps.children &&
          ListboxProps.children.map((p: any, index: any) => {
            return (
              <ListItem {...p.props} key={index}>
                {p.props.children}
              </ListItem>
            )
          })}
      </List>
    </div>
  )
}
```

Comment: Can you upload your code to codesandbox? So I can check your issue easier.

Comment: @Michael here is the link [link](https://codesandbox.io/s/autocomplete-autohighlight-not-working-rskms) .I'm suspecting the its the ListboxComponent of AutoComplete causing the issue.